# find the solution basis to $ty'-(t+2)y=-2t^2-2t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

given 1.y=y(t) 2.$ty'-(t+2)y=-2t^2-2t$. 
the solution to the equation can be expressed as linear combination of t and another basis.
please find this basis=?

I set the solution:$C1*t+C2*t*f(t)$,then i get:$-C2*tf(t)-C2*t^2f(t)+C2*t^2*f'(t)=-2t^2-2t$

then  I　don't know what to do...can anyone help?thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

we have $$ty'-(t+2)y=-2t^2-2t$$
at first we solve the equation $$ty'-(t+2)y=0$$ which gives us $$y(t)=e^t\cdot t^2C$$
after this you will get a particular solution with $y_p=mt+n$ this gives us $$y_p=-2t$$

Answer (score 1):

$y = 2t$ is a solution of $ty^\prime - (t+2)y = -2t^2 - 2t.$ what you need to do now is find solutions to the homogeneous problem $ty^\prime - (t+2)y = 0$

can you separate the variables and find $y?$

Comment: thanks,I solve it after separation of variables